# Failing to create a jar with Cradle in CMD (Win 10) (Task not found in root project)

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to follow directions on how to build the necessary jars on https://github.com/kaleido-io/kaleido-corda-samples/blob/master/README.md but I am met with the following messages:

```
C:\Windows\System32>d:

D:\>cd D:\gradle-6.7.1

D:\gradle-6.7.1>Gradle buildAll

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'buildAll' not found in root project 'gradle-6.7.1'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 791ms
```

"D:\gradle-6.7.1" is the directory of my Gradle folder.
If I understand correctly, I need to create a root project first but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Go to the root of that project you linked to and run `.\gradlew.bat buildAll`

Comment: Well, there is no project yet. What I have now is an unzipped archive from the official site and that's all.

Comment: What was the purpose of linking to that README? Isn't that the project you are trying to build?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you and what I needed to do. Did as you told, everything worked out. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to learn more about the gradlew (gradle wrapper) file, [see the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)